# How to access the object of String pool

Tags: java, string

Can we able to access the object in String pool which is does not not have any reference.
Here is code :

```
String str ="abc";
str.toUpperCase();
System.out.println(str); // System.out.println(str.toUpperCase());

Output : abc
```

Here I am performing the `toUpperCase()`  operation on `str`. In String pool one object will be created for this `str.toUpperCase();`. Can we able to access this object.? if yes how?

Comment: What language? In Java you have to use the return value `str=str.toUpperCase();` This has nothing to do with string pools.

Comment: Hi holger, Thank a lot.. Even this line 'System.out.println(str.toUpperCase());' code will give the expected result. But my question is what happened to this line in memory 'str.toUpperCase();//it contains result "ABC"'... can we able to access this result without assigning to be any variable and without using system.out.println() statements.

Comment: If you don’t use the return value, that object becomes *unreachable*. The garbage collector will free its memory in the next gc cycle then.

Answer (score 2):

This is where java documentation is used .... Refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase()

str.toUpperCase() returns a string converted to upper case, you have to assign it to another string variable or do a self assignment, so you can access it later.

Comment: @Basilevs the question has nothing to do with interning.

Comment: @Holger, what other string pool do you think its about? Heap?

Comment: @Basilevs question is about 'accessing the object' which has the 'upper case string'. And that link has the information he would need.

Comment: @Basilevs the questioner simply doesn’t know how to use the return value of `toUppercase`. Otherwise his question doesn’t make any sense. Feel free to provide a better answer if you disagree. I don’t see your answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
String str ="abc";       // 1
str.toUpperCase();       // 2
System.out.println(str); // 3
```

in above code

First line will create new Object of `String` with value "abc" and assign it to the reference variable `str`.

Second line will create the new Object of `String` because `String` class is immutable so original Object `str` will not change. but here we are not assigning the new object which is created in line 2 so it will be lost somewhere in Heap area.

That is why in line 3 printing value is "abc".

if you want to use the new Object created by `str.toUpperCase()` than have to assign that in a new reference variable.
or
alternative option is update the original `String` Object like this

```
str = str.toUpperCase();
```

but in above operation, the original Object `str` containing the value "abc" will be lost in the Heap area !!!!!

You can find details about [working with `String` by example here](http://kishangajjar.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/unit-5-prog-1-introduction-and-basics-of-string/).

Comment: @ Krishn: thank you so much .. you mean we cant access the result of 'str.toUpperCase()' without assign to same/other String variable.

Comment: yes exactly...we have to assign it to any reference variable in order to use that...else it will be an lost object somewhere in Heap area...!!