# String literals in Java

Tags: java, string

I've just started learning Java and came across this:

```
String s = "Hello";
String s1 = "Hello";
if(s.equals("Hello") && s.equals(s1))
{
    System.out.println("Equal");
}
```

The first condition in `if` statement compares the String literal `s` against a sequence of characters where as the second statement compares `s` against another string literal `s1`. Both the comparisons turn out to be true.

My understanding is that `s` will hold the reference to `"Hello"` and so does `s1`. As both `s` and `s1` hold references to `"Hello"`, they can be compared and are always equal (because of the 'common string pool').

My question is: How can `s`, which holds a reference, be compared to the actual string `"Hello"` which is a character sequence?? Is there any logic or is it just the implementation which takes care of the memory references and then compares the two??

Please do correct me if my understanding is wrong...

Comment: s == "Hello" is NOT the same like s.equals("Hello"). equals checks if the strings are equal and not if the references are the same.

Comment: be aware that `s` and `s1` will at most _usually_ be equal. The string pool is no guarantee!!

Comment: @ljgw - what do you mean by  "at most usually be equal. The string pool is no guarantee!!".

Comment: You need to know some basic about `String` and String handling in Java...Possible duplicate of [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569063/how-to-access-the-object-of-string-pool/19574415#19574415).
you can refer [this](http://kishangajjar.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/unit-5-prog-1-introduction-and-basics-of-string/)...

Comment: -1 for screwing up my edits that corrected the spelling in the title and removed the major tag to instead add a more relevant term.  :(

Comment: @TheLostMind it's just a (too) friendly warning saying you should not rely on the the `intern`ment of strings (see T.J Crowders answer)

Comment: Forgiven.  Down vote removed.  Tip:  Don't use the 'back button' to edit a post.  There is a small link below a question that says 'edit'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is: How can 's', which holds a reference, be compared to the actual string "Hello" which is a character sequence?

`"Hello"` is *not* a character sequence. It's a `String`. (`String` does implement the [`CharSequence` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html), but that's not the same thing.) So by the time you're using `equals` or `==`, you're comparing `String` instances, not some special thing. A `String` literal *is* a `String` (complete with a reference to it where the literal was written in the source).

It seemed at first as though you were confused about `equals` and `==`. Re-reading, I'm not sure you are, but just in case: `equals` compares two objects for equivalence; if the two objects are `String`s, it returns `true` if they have the same sequence of characters. `==` compares two object references and evaluates `true` if they point to **the same object**. `==` is sometimes `true` for what seem to be different `String` objects because `String` literals are implicitly [`intern`'d](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) (put in a common pool and reused from it) to save memory, and so two separate but equivalent literals actually do end up referring to the same object. *Never* rely on that. Using `==` to compare `String`s is almost always an error (the cases where it isn't are very much edge-cases). Use `equals`.

Comment: Now I see why I got downvoted. I misunderstood his question (Although I already had my Coffee).

Comment: @MarounMaroun: What you need is sleep. :-) Happy New Year!

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the `equals` method, which compares the two objects for equivalence - it does not check that the two references are to the same instance of the object. To check for two references to the same object you would use `s == s1`

Answer (score 2):

if you see the source code of `equals` you can understand that the equals method compare the value of strings by each
character. If you used `==` that will compare the referecnce only.

```
   public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
      if (this == anObject) {
            return true;
        }
       if (anObject instanceof String) {
            String anotherString = (String)anObject;
           int n = count;
            if (n == anotherString.count) {
                char v1[] = value;
                char v2[] = anotherString.value;
              int i = offset;
               int j = anotherString.offset;
               while (n-- != 0) {
                    if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
                       return false;
                }
               return true;
           }
       }
       return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `equals` method is called, the thing that goes onto the stack is a reference to whatever is passed.  So when you write `s.equals("Hello")`, one of the things on the stack is a reference to `"Hello"`.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: How can s, which holds a reference, be compared to the
>   actual string "Hello" which is a character sequence?? Is there any
>   logic or is it just the implementation which takes care of the memory
>   references and then compares the two??

The algorithm for checking the Strings for equality involves:

1. If the String objects are equals as per == operator, true is returned.
2. If the == returns false then each character of both the strings are compared and if a difference if found, immediately false is returned.
3. If after comparing all characters of both the strings, no difference is found in characters and length of strings, true is returned.

The following is the defaullt implementation of `.equals()` method in String class :

```
 public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
      if (this == anObject) {
         return true;
      }
      if (anObject instanceof String) {
         String anotherString = (String)anObject;
         int n = count;
         if (n == anotherString.count) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = offset;
            int j = anotherString.offset;
            while (n-- != 0) {
              if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
                 return false;
               }
            return true;
           }
         }
       return false;
    }
```

To check for two references to the same object you would use s == s1 .

To compare two values use `.equals()` method.